# copying string from one string pointer array to another

Tags: c++

```
if(temp>final_hash_index_one)
            {
                string *tmp = new string[temp+1];
                std::copy(level_two, tmp, final_hash_index_one+1);
                delete [] level_two;
                level_two = tmp;
            }
```

this method is not working and is giving me an exception that is "invalid null pointer"!!

```
string *tmp = new string[some_size];
string *level_two = new string[some_size];
```

how to copy contents from level_two to tmp??? in case of string one; string two . we can copy the string through loop. but what in this case??

Comment: Are these `std::string`? Why are you making a pointer to it? Why aren't you using an `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: havent used vectors uptill now that is why using strings!! am doing perfect hashing so am dealing with dynamically string pointer arrays!!

Comment: level_two has strings at different locations particularly indexes . i want to dynamically change the size of level_two array. for that i want to copy contents to tmp with new size place another string at a location in temp then reallocate new size of level_two and then copy back the contents from tmp to level_two!!

Comment: @HarisRiaz please reply to the questions of birryree. one-by-one.

Comment: how can i copy each string from level_two to tmp string by string through loop??

Answer (score 3):

First, STL copy takes the form of

```
OutputIterator copy ( InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result );
```

So you see that the result is the last argument.

Second, if you are into STL (which is very good!) you don't need arrays anymore. Use vectors of strings:

```
vector<string> tmp(some_size);
vector<string> level_two(some_size);
```

Copying from level_to to tmp is simply:

```
tmp = level_two;  // (!)
```

Comment: any way to perform this operation through pointer array of string ??

Comment: You can copy using a loop, string by string. But again, vectors are much more easy to deal with.

Comment: ok . will it be a nested loop?? exactly this is what is want to know! how can i do that! i asked my friend with me right now and we came on the same argument that it will be a string by string copy! tried a few things but gives exception! how to do it through loop??

Comment: If the arrays are `string tmp[some_size], level_two[some_size]` then you do `for (i = 0; i < some_size; i++) {tmp[i] = level_two[i];}`